# Фонетический разбор слова "строитель"

Tags: фонетика

Здравствуйте. Как бы вы разобрали фонетически слово СТРОИТЕЛЬ. Спор вышел: что же слышится в слове "-тЕль" или "-тИль". По-моему, нужно писать основной звук Э с призвуком И, а учитель говорит, что нельзя. Есть правило. Действительно есть такое правило? Спасибо.

Comment: Прежде, чем спорить с учителем, Вы бы ошибки у себя проверили. Я Вам кучу знаков препинания расставила.

Answer (score 2):

Учитель прав. Названного вами звука в заударном слоге в принципе быть не может. Для школьного разбора вполне достаточно приближения [т'ил']. Хотя на самом деле там, конечно, редуцированный заднего ряда: [т'ьл'].